# C++ Polymorphism and Overriding

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism, overriding

I'm having a hard time getting this working in C++, I've managed it in C# but I've not used C++ much so I'm not sure on the syntax.

The purpose of this is for a simple state manager, each state inherits from a base class called "state".

I've gotten overriding to work but I can't seem to manage the polymorphism aspect. That is that I cannot have an object "State currentState" and set that object to equal "menuState" and have it run the desired function, I know this is because it is only finding the signature for the State class but I am unsure how to avoid it. Here's some simplified code so that someone can help me understand.

```
// stringstreams
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

// State.h
class State{
public:
  virtual void drawState();
};

// State.cpp
void State::drawState() {
    cout << "Base state.\n";
}

// MenuState.h
class MenuState: public State {
public:
  virtual void drawState();
};


// MenuState.cpp
void MenuState::drawState() {
    cout << "Menu state.\n";
    State::drawState();
}

int main ()
{
    State currentState;
    MenuState menuState;

    currentState = menuState;
    currentState.drawState();

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

If you change "State currentState" to create an object of MenuState the code will work as I require it to, however I need it to be the parent class so that I can set the current state to other states I will create in the future such as GameState.

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Polymorphism doesn't work with plain objects because of slicing. You have to use references or (smart) pointers. In your case, pointers, as references can't be re-assigned:

```
int main ()
{
    State* currentState = NULL;
    MenuState menuState;

    currentState = &menuState;
    currentState->drawState(); //calls MenuState::drawState()

    NextState nextState; //fictional class
    currentState = &nextState;
    currentState->drawState(); //calls NextState::drawState()

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

In your code:

```
State currentState;
MenuState menuState;

currentState = menuState;
```

the assignment slices `menuState` - it basically just copies the `State` part of it to `currentState`, losing all other type information.

Comment: Yes, C++ is different from C# in that by default C# user defined types are all 'reference types'. Translating `Foo myFoo;` from C# to  C++ results in something like `Foo *myFoo = new Foo;` (depending on the actual definition of `Foo` in C#, I understand C# added user-defined value-types).

Comment: Worked a charm! Quick response, informative too! I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 2):

Change your code to:

```
int main ()
{
    State *currentState;

    currentState = new MenuState();
    currentState->drawState();

    system("pause");
    delete(currentState)
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There's no need for dynamic allocation (which should be avoided where possible), plus, this code leaks memory.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore Do you say this because this OP's code doesn't implement polymorphic destruction (virtual-dtors)? If so, how is that the fault of the *deleter* rather than the OP's class? (and +1 for the completely unnecessary dynamic allocation in the first place).

Comment: @WhozCraig the second part of my comment doesn't apply anymore (originally, the answer didn't have the `delete currentState`). Now, it just leads to undefined behavior (because of the reason you stated).

Comment: @LuchianGrigore ok. cause I didn't see an edit history (damn safari prolly jerking me around again).

Comment: @WhozCraig it's not safari, you can stealth-edit an answer withing 5 minutes.

Comment: ah, I should have added a note about the edit in my answer. sorry - I edited it based on @LuchianGrigore 's mem leak note. this discussion taught me a few things I didn't know about C++, much appreciated =)